# Bash: killing a specific task after starting it in a script

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script to start a few services to make my life and that of my colleagues easier:

```
cd "${redis}"
redis-server ./redis.conf &
cd "${serverFolder}"
php artisan serve &
php artisan queue:listen &
cd "${clientFolder}"
laravel-echo-server start &
```

All is good. But now I also want to make a stop bash script. How? I thought about using `killall`, but if I have e.g. another artisan web server running it would kill that too. I could grab the PID, but then the same issue arises. How can I differentiate between the possible other running web server and the correct one?

Is doing this in some way possible?

Comment: Get pids with `$!`, kill pids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the PIDs in a bash array and create a killer script:

```
declare -a PIDS=()
cd "${redis}"
redis-server ./redis.conf & PIDS+=($!)
cd "${serverFolder}"
php artisan serve & PIDS+=($!)
php artisan queue:listen & PIDS+=($!)
cd "${clientFolder}"
laravel-echo-server start & PIDS+=($!)
printf "kill -9 %s\n" "${PIDS[@]}" > kill-script.sh
```

And then, run the killer script to stop the servers you started and only them.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the PID of it just after running it by `"$!"` or by doing this

```
temp=`ps -eaf | grep <processname> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
pid_array=($temp)
PID=${pid_array[${#pid_array[@]}-1]}
```

From this, you can get the PID of the process you have just run.
then you can kill it whenever you want.

Does this address your problem?